# SSIS(Flat file connection manager is not using variable value as connection manager)

Tags: ssis

In SSIS,I have taken flat file connection manager.
At the time of creation of Flat file connection manager I have passed file name using brows button.
But I want to pass this value using variable for that I have taken one variable with value.
and in FFCM property window,I have set the Expression with the connetionString with another file path.

But when I run this,FFCM not using variable value,Its using which I had passed at the time of creation FFCM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you use your flat file connection ?

In the FFCM property window, under "Expressions", did you properly set the connectionString to your variable ? Because this should override the value you've set when you clicked on "browse". That's the only thing to do, really.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you have done so far.  " for that I have taken one variable with value", and ",I have set the Expression with the connetionString with another file path."   I'm not sure what you mean by either of these statements.   As Thomas says, assuming you are populating your variable correctly, you should set the connectionString Expression to the value of the variable.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your comment. I have set variable value to connection string under expression properly.how do I check that it is assigned properly or not?

Comment: @TabAlleman: Thanks for your comments.I think Thomas has understood  . u can refer my above chat.

Comment: @Akshay It's not that clear... To check the values of variables at runtime, you can add a break point to a component. Then, add a "Watch" or browse the "Locals" tab. To check the flat file connection string, it should appear in the execution result under "Flat File source information"

Comment: @Thomas: I am passing the Url of file which is in sharepoint Library. like this (http:/server/sites/sitecollectionname/Library/fileName)

Comment: You cannot do that. Download the file first to a local or network path (ie. "C:\path\to\file" or "\\server\path\to\file") and use this connection string in the FFCM.

Comment: You can do that by using a script task or a custom component. Google "download file http ssis"